# Validate range of values against another range of values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, validation, range

Similar to how CountIf validates a single value against a range of values (or, CountIfs validating a range of values against criteria), is there a way to validate a range of values against another range of values?

EX:
First Range (R1)
a1:a5 contains a,b,c,d,e

Second Range (R2)
b1:b contains a,b,c

Upon checking whether R1 values are in R2, the outcome is FALSE due to 'd' and 'e' not in R2.
Just wondering if there's already a function, or is there an easy way to build one.
Thanks,
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cook up a formula that will do this. For example, you can use `SUMPRODUCT` to check an array of conditions for `COUNTIF` and tally how many find a match. Then, compare that tally to the count of conditions you were searching for.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(B1:B5,A1:A5)>0))=COUNTA(A1:A5)
```

A walk-through of the evaluation of this formula with the sample data you provided:

1. `=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(B1:B5,{a,b,c,d,e})>0))=COUNTA(A1:A5)`
2. `=SUMPRODUCT(--({1,1,1,0,0}>0))=COUNTA(A1:A5)`
3. `=SUMPRODUCT(--({TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}))=COUNTA(A1:A5)`
4. `=SUMPRODUCT({1,1,1,0,0})=COUNTA(A1:A5)`
5. `=3=COUNTA(A1:A5)`
6. `=3=5`
7. `=FALSE`

Comment: Thanks That's brilliant. Is there a way to indicate which cell violates the comparison? (preferably by highlighting the cells)